# Decode byte array

Tags: c#, modbus

I want to decode a byte array received from a modbus communication. This is the hex string representing the byte array:

```
01 11 0C 46 57 35 32 39 37 30 31 52 30 2E 35 FE 27
```

I want to split in 3 parts:

1. 01 11 0C
2. 46 57 35 32 39 37 30 31 52 30 2E 35
3. FE 27

For transforming from byte to hex I use this method:

```
 #region ByteToHex
    /// <summary>
    /// method to convert a byte array into a hex string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comByte">byte array to convert</param>
    /// <returns>a hex string</returns>
    public string ByteToHex(byte[] comByte)
    {
        //create a new StringBuilder object
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(comByte.Length * 3);
        //loop through each byte in the array
        foreach (byte data in comByte)
            //convert the byte to a string and add to the stringbuilder
            builder.Append(Convert.ToString(data, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' '));
        //return the converted value
        return builder.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
```

How can I split the returned string from that method to return:
the first 3 bytes are:

1. Server id
2. Function code
3. Byte count

The next N bytes (see 3.) are the payload; the last 2 are a CRC16.

I need to find the payload; it is a string.

Comment: When it's surely a fixed length use `String.Substring()`

Comment: If it's not a fixed lenght, what are the logics behind the splitting? why is it 3 hex numbers, 12 hex numbers, 2 hex numbers?

Comment: Are you interested in a) a string with hex digits b) the binary/integer value of the sub-parts c) some more elaborate decoding?

Comment: the first 3 hex number are  Server id, function code, byte count. the next 12 are the data, the lest 2 are CRC high and low

Comment: i need the 12 hex number to convert in text, because i need to read the holding register from a device

Comment: My interest is to do some more elaborate decoding

Comment: Please modify your question then

Comment: BTW to convert to hex you can also write a simple one liner: `string hex = BitConverter.ToString(comByte).Replace("-", " ");`

Comment: @CodeCaster I think its more a "There come bytes from a device, how handle that" which is way more interesting: It is **not** a string split. (albeit mentioned in the question)

Comment: @DrKoch "How to split a byte array" (Buffer.BlockCopy, ArraySegment) is also very well documented on MSDN and this site.

Comment: @CodeCaster We talk about "decoding raw bytes" here. This is more than splitting.

Comment: @DrKoch and that too is very well documented. All I'm saying is that OP should show what they have tried. Starting to decode a byte array by turning it into a hex string won't get you far.

Comment: The string from device come after i send a client request, hex string but not every time the device replay DATA=12 hex number that depends on registry that i request, but the header 3 hex number and the last 2 hex they have every time the same length.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a online tool to verify the decode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes little sense to turn the input into a hexadecimal string. You need to decode the information the bytes hold. What they hold exactly depends on the documentation, which you merely paraphrased. I'll take a shot at it:

```
public class ModbusRequest
{
    public byte ServerId { get; set; }
    public byte FunctionCode { get; set; }
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}

public ModbusRequest DecodeMessage(byte[] message)
{
    var result = new ModbusRequest();

    // Simply copy bytes 0 and 1 into the destination structure.
    result.ServerId = message[0];
    result.FunctionCode = message[1];

    byte stringLength = message[2];

    // Assuming ASCII encoding, see docs.
    result.Payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 3, stringLength);

    // Get the CRC bytes.
    byte[] crc = new byte[2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(message, 4 + stringLength, crc, 0, 2);

    // TODO: verify CRC.

    return result;

}
```

To verify the CRC, find out which format is being used. I recommend using [classless-hasher](https://bitbucket.org/jayclassless/classless-hasher/wiki/Home) for implementing various CRC variants.

Comment: classless-hasher - nice! Didn't know that one.

Comment: i try the code from above but i get "invalid expression term 'byte' "

Comment: @user fixed, I had `byte` somewhere where `message` should be.

Comment: now i have a problem with  result.Payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(comByte, 3, stringLength);    An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @user then I suggest you go debugging. Inspect the values of the various variables, for example `comByte` and `stringLength`.

Comment: comByte = 17 and stringLength = 12

Comment: @user don't tell me, I can't see your code. You need to debug it.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

If the bytes returnes represent structured data you should **not** convert all bytes to strings. Instead convert the bytes according to their meaning:

```
int serverId = Convert.ToInt32(byte[0]);
int functionCode = Convert.ToInt32(byte[1]);
int byteCount = Convert.ToInt32(byte[2]);
```

As soon as you know the length of the data part, you may decode this data:

```
for(int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
{
    // do something with byte[3+i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = ByteToHex(comByte);
string partOne = str.Substring(0, 8);
string partTwo = str.Substring(9, 35);
string partThree = str.Substring(45, 5);
```

Comment: There are two characters per _hex-byte_: `string partOne = str.Substring(0, 6);`and so on

Comment: Of course there is! My mistake. Editet the answer now.

Comment: I think the string also includes spaces. So the first part should be `str.Substring(0, 7)` ...

Comment: after every hex number is a space

Answer (score 0):

First change the signature of the existing `ByteToHex` method so the input parameter is a `IEnumerable<byte>` instead of a `byte[]`.

Then use:

```
var str1 = ByteToHex(new ArraySegment<byte>(yourBytes, 0, 3));
var str2 = ByteToHex(new ArraySegment<byte>(yourBytes, 3, 12));
var str3 = ByteToHex(new ArraySegment<byte>(yourBytes, 15, 2));
```

This use of `ArraySegment<>` is possible since .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012).

---

PS! The entire body of the method could be simplified:

```
public static string ByteToHex(IEnumerable<byte> comByte)
{
  return string.Join(" ", comByte.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
}
```

Here the capital `X` means hex format with capital "digits" A to F, and the `2` means pad with zeroes to length two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to split a byte array, then do it directly on the array - don't convert to string beforehand! The resulting code will be far easier to understand.

Afterwards you can still convert parts of it to hex string or in your case to a text-string with an encoding rather then the hex.

For Subarrays I have this little extension:

```
// Returns the SubArray starting from index and covering the amount of length items.
public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] data, int index, int length)
{
    T[] result = new T[length];
    System.Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
    return result;
}
```

As mentionend in another answer, since .NET 4.5 you could also use the new [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

With this you can simply split like this:

```
const int HEADER_LENGTH = 3; //1 Byte ServerId, 1 Byte Function Code, 1 Byte ByteCount
const int CRC_LENGTH = 2;

var bytes = new byte[]{0x01, 0x11,  0x0C, 0x46, 0x57, 0x35, 0x32, 0x39, 0x37, 0x30, 0x31, 0x52, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x35, 0xFE, 0x27};
int payloadLength = bytes.Count() - HEADER_LENGTH - CRC_LENGTH;

//.NET 4.5 solution
var textbytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, HEADER_LENGTH, payloadLength).ToArray();

//pre 4.5 solution with extension
var textbytes = bytes.SubArray(HEADER_LENGTH, payloadLength);

var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(textbytes); //FW529701R0.5
```